# numpy.distutils setup not rendering README.md correctly on pypi

Tags: python, numpy, packaging, setup.py, distutils

I am using

```
from numpy.distutils.core import setup
```

for packaging up some code to pypi.

However the README.md file does not render correctly. This works fine if I use `setup` from setuptools, but I am not sure why it isn't working with the numpy version (I need the numpy version to build some lib used by the code).

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import subprocess
    try:
        assert(check_python_version() )
    except AssertionError:
        sys.exit("Exiting: Please use python version > 3.5")
    install_numpy()
    from numpy.distutils.core import setup
    install_dependencies()
    build_f90_src_for_tests()

    exec(open('crystal_torture/version.py').read())

    args = check_f2py_compiler()
    this_directory = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
    with open(os.path.join(this_directory, 'README.md')) as f:
        long_description = f.read()

    config = {'name':'CrystalTorture',
              'version':__version__,
              'description':'A Crystal Tortuosity Module',
              'long_description': long_description,
     'url':'https://github.com/connorourke/crystaltorture',
     'python_requires':'>=3.5',
     'packages':['crystal_torture'],
     'package_dir':{'crystal_torture':'crystal_torture'},
     'package_data':{'crystal_torture':['*so','*tort*','*dist*','*o*']},
     'include_package_data':True,
     'license': 'MIT',
     'install_requires': ['ddt',
                          'coverage',
                          'f90wrap',
                          'numpy',
                          'pymatgen'
                          ]
}

    config_tort = setup_tort_ext(args,parent_package='crystal_torture',top_path='')
    config2 = dict(config,**config_tort.todict())

    setup(**config2)
```

The rendering can be seen at:

https://test.pypi.org/project/crystal-torture/#description

Any hot tips are certainly welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Your `README.txt` is in markdown format. You try to set [`'long_description_content_type':'text/markdown'`](https://github.com/connorourke/crystal_torture/blob/8c7e6fdc1fbbbc08dde9825cfe2a2f9caa0e995a/setup.py#L126) in `setup.py` but I guess `numpy.distutils` ignores it. Perhaps it's simply too old; `'long_description_content_type'` was added to `setuptools` not so long ago. I think you better switch to `setuptools` or change the format to reStructuredText.

PS. Please also fix [`url`](https://github.com/connorourke/crystal_torture/blob/8c7e6fdc1fbbbc08dde9825cfe2a2f9caa0e995a/setup.py#L129): it's `crystal_torture` with underscore.

Comment: I had tried restructured text, plain text and .md. There was an error in the .rst file that prevented it from rendering properly - which I discovered by using a resturtcured text editor. Thanks for spotting the url.